# Customize the form-portion of a view

Tags: views

There might be a really simple answer for this, but I haven't found it yet.

I'm using a view with a few exposed filters.  The form it generates is too basic, and I want to restructure it a bit, with some "+ advanced" expanding/collapsing divs and things like that.

What method do I hook for this?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you lookup https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters module ?

Comment: Actually I had, but the module didn't advertise the collapsing-advanced-area feature!  Nowhere on the page do I see it mentioned.  But, I just ran across the checkbox in the admin screen.  *sigh*

Comment: Though, it really messes up the HTML structure of the collapsed elements... there is no generic way to select the label elements of each filter, now, without also selecting checkbox elements; the 'form-item' CSS class appears multiple times per form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [views-exposed-form.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-exposed-form.tpl.php/7) template.
In this overrided template you can putup own div wrapper etc.
How to override any template(tpl) visit [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-overrides).

You can also use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). It perform alterations before a form is rendered. So using this add some alteration on form.

Comment: Thanks!  I see from your link that I could have found this in the API doc of the views module if I looked harder.  I'll give it more effort next time.